# Import hooks into React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement hooks into a React (^16.6.0) application using TypeScript

```
import * as React, {useState}  from 'react';
```

Any idea what is the right syntax for this import?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) supports a limited set of syntax variations.

It can be:

```
import React, {useState}  from 'react';
```

The downside is that entire library is imported, because `React` is default export and cannot be tree-shaken. Since the presence of `React` import is needed to use JSX syntax, a more efficient way is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState}  from 'react';
```

[Hooks were introduced in pre-release React 16.7](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). `react` version constraint should be `^16.7.0-alpha.0`, `@types/react` should be `^16.7.0`.

Comment: Sorry still not working it gives me the following
     'Module '"C:/web-client-ts/node_modules/@types/react/index"' has no exported member 'useState'.'

Comment: It should be because of the version in "@types/react" is not yet updated. Please `npm i @types/react@latest` and try again

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error on `"@types/react": "^16.8.17"`.  Looking at it's type def file, it was missing the `useState` function for some reason, though it was mentioned in the comments of other hooks like `useReducer`.

Upgrading to `"@types/react": "^16.8.18"` with `npm i @types/react@latest` fixed it.

Comment: still giving the error

Comment: Also bugged in the 17.x.x branch.  17.0.27 bugged, 17.0.44 fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting Ts Server Helped in my case
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try installing `npm i @types/react`

Comment: Suggesting to install @types/react already covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56345351/